# Add custom name to base url on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

How can I add to my domain a custom name, as for example:

mydomain.com/**test/**

So if visit any page or post the URL will be

mydomain.com/**test/**...

Comment: Why would you want this?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is to install Wordpress in a directory called `/test/` relative to you webserver root.

For example, if your webserver root is `/var/www/` then you can install it in `/var/www/test/`.

Then all of your WordPress URLs will begin with mydomain.com/test/

Alternatively, you can add rewrite rules to your webserver configuration, but that gets more complicated.